# Can I set a block to be executed per frame update during a CATransaction?

Tags: ios, core-animation

I'd like to update the color of sublayers of a CATransformLayer as it animates. Is there a way to set a block to execute upon each frame update for the duration of the animation CATransaction? If no, what is the best way to get the colors of the sublayers updating during the animation?

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:duration];
// The imaginary functionality of the following imaginary code is what I want to implement--though not at all in any form that resembles its imaginary form below
[CATransaction setBlockThatExecutesPerFrameUpdate:^{
    for ( CALayer *layer in self.transformLayer.sublayers )
        [layer doSomethingWith:layer.presentationLayer.transform];
}];
// What I imagine ends here
self.transformLayer.transform = [self sideTransform];
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Show the code for the animation you're actually doing, please.

Answer (score 2):

Animation takes place in its own process (the "animation server") off the main thread. No sort of notification comes back to "your" code on a per-frame basis during the animation, and rightly so, since that would risk slowing down the animation intolerably, not to mention possibly interfering with your code. If you want colors to change at the same time that some other animation is going on, just animate the change in color with the same duration as the other animation. You can ask for several animations and they will all take place together when the animation server gets control.

Comment: What Matt said. (He beat me to it, but his answer is 100% on the money, as usual.)

Comment: Nice answer. The only thing I would add is that you can use a `CADisplayLink` and get a layer's presentation values at each frame as it animates. You won't be able to change any presentation layer values though, only model layer values (and they won't be displayed until after the animation)

Comment: @originaluser2 Very good point. I did think of that, but I felt about this the way you felt about my origin-at-upper-left — it would be pedagogically unwise to get off into those weeds.

Comment: @matt indeed, let's leave sleeping dogs lie on that one ;)

Comment: Thanks so much for your guidance! At least I have some ideas about what I can rule out. I edited my question to be more clear about what I need. I'm currently trying to see what I can do by subclassing CATransformLayer and CALayer because I found some code that seems like it does what I need successfully by doing so--so I'm trying to understand the found code and implement it for my case. If I'm successful, I'll post that code, otherwise, I'll mark this as the answer.